# Firefox string resources: How to get localized friendly languages names?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox extension that involves dictionaries in various languages and dialects. I want to display a dialog to the user to select spell checking dictionaries for the available languages.
It will be tedious for the user to select from values like en-US, ar-EG, en-GB, etc., so, I want to display the localized language names like what Firefox does in this screenshot
[image: Dictionaries]

This is the dictionary selection menu on my Arabic Firefox displaying the names of the two languages en-US and ar.

How to do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to find and use these strings:

1- I downloaded the [whole Firefox source code](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/) and extracted it.

2- I searched the source files for the name "New Zealand". This unique country name should exist only in the file I'm looking for. Rather than using general terms like English, United States, Arabic, etc.

3- The search led me to two interesting files: regionNames.properties and languageNames.properties. The first has the names of all countries and the other has the names of all languages. Firefox should be using the two sets of strings to display dictionary names.

4- I found that the two files can be fetched from the URLs chrome://global/locale/languageNames.properties and chrome://global/locale/regionNames.properties, so, I used the [string bundle service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIStringBundleService) and the [string bundle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIStringBundle) objects to load and use the resources.

Here's a code sample:

- On the top of my main.js file:

  ```
  const {Cc, Ci, Cu}  = require("chrome"),
        stringBundles = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/stringbundle;1"].getService(Ci.nsIStringBundleService);
  ```
- Then I have this piece of code in another method:

  ```
  let languagesNamesBundle = stringBundles.createBundle("chrome://global/locale/languageNames.properties"),
      countriesNames = stringBundles.createBundle("chrome://global/locale/regionNames.properties");

  console.log(languagesNamesBundle.GetStringFromName("ar")); // العربية Arabic
  console.log(languagesNamesBundle.GetStringFromName("af")); // الأفريكانية Afrikaans
  console.log(countriesNames.GetStringFromName("fj")); // فيجي Fiji
  console.log(countriesNames.GetStringFromName("cr")); // كوستا ريكا Costa Rica
  ```

And this is what I wanted. Now I can compose dictionary names from languages and countries names.
I'll update the answer to add the path of the project repository after I publish the final result.

Comment: No need to download whole firefox code, there is dxr.mozilla.org thats the nightly version source code :) excellent work and excellent solution :)

Comment: @Noitidart Thank you for guiding me to this. It will be useful next time

Answer (score 1):

This is very easily doable. I have some very basic templates for localization here:

https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/xhtml-xul

https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/properties

properties files are for within privelaged js file localiztion. and .dtd is used for xul/xhtml/and inline javascript.

Comment: Greetings and thanks for your answer. I've already seen your examples before as they are published on the MDN. These are examples of localized addons. If I follow this method, I'll have to write my own .properties files that have the names of all the possible languages and dialects, and I'll have to do this for the main languages the addon targets, which is not what I want.

I want to leverage what already exists inside Firefox. Firefox already have the names (English(United States), Arabic, English (New Zealand), etc.) localized to the current language of the browser and I want to fetch them.

Comment: Ooo thats acutally a great idea you should be able to pull up their localized files, Ill take a look. Can you point me in direction on how to pull up the languages menu in Firefox

Comment: I've already downloaded the whole [Firefox source code](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/)! and searched it for the phrase "New Zealand" and found two interesting files: languageNames.properties which has all languages names, and regionNames.properties which has the names of all countries. I think they compose what appears in the languages menu using values from these two files. Now, how to know the string bundles which contain these files so that I can load them and use in my addon?

Comment: I can read them using chrome://global/locale/languageNames.properties and chrome://global/locale/regionNames.properties How to load them into the application?

Comment: I knew how to do it using string bundles. Thanks for your help. I'll publish an answer soon and upvote your answer

Comment: Yep just load in those .properties or .dtd files as you would your own, so just like done in those l10n gists, great job there! Looking forward to you solution :)

Comment: I added my answer. Thanks for your help and the good work you do on the MDN.

Comment: My pleasure! Thanks for the recognition, I hope it helps :)